# Use Rollback query for delete command in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to run a delete and update query in production database and the where condition is too complicated to apply. I have created the query but before executing I want to test this query. So I want to rollback the query before applying actual delete query. How to do that?

Comment: perform a select with the same where condition to test your logic....

Answer (score 3):

Start the transaction using `BEGIN` `TRANS` and then execute the query.

Then look at the results of the query, if they are what you desire then you can commit the transaction else to roll it back using `ROLLBACK` Command.

Here is an example:

```
BEGIN TRAN t1 -- Begin the transaction

      DELETE * FROM Table_Name WHERE col=1  -- Do the "scary operation" in 
      --the production environment
      SELECT * FROM Table_Name -- Make sure it did what you thought it should 
      have.
      -- Then depending on results: 

COMMIT TRAN t1 -- Satisfied with results - Commits the transaction (delete 
operation)

ROLLBACK TRAN t1 -- Results not as expected - Rollback the transaction.
```

Comment: but.... you should mention that in production this could block other processes while the transaction is open and data is being checked....

Comment: I thought about mentioning that it is bad practice to modify code on-the-fly in production but decided against.

Comment: Is it required to check `@@TRANCOUNT` before `ROLLBACK`?

Comment: you check CATCH EXCEPTION